# Копирование папок с заменой Java

Tags: java, файловая-система

Есть задача скопировать куча папок в одну папку, в этих папках одинаковые файлы\папки, и мне их надо скопировать с заменой, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы уже придумали, как будете выбирать, какой из 2х одинаковых файлов оставить?

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`java.nio.file.Files::copy(path1, path2, copyOption)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) с опцией `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`.